# Error when encoding UITouchesEvent as NSData

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdata, nskeyedarchiver, objective-c-category

I have an NSDictionary containing some objects: an NSSet of UITouches, a UIEvent, and an NSString.

When I try to encode the dictionary to NSData, the string encodes properly. I had an error with the UITouches being encoded, but I found a way to extend the class with some code so that a UITouch can be encoded. However, I still can't encode the UIEvent (which is actually a UITouchesEvent). How can I extend the UIEvent or UIInternalEvent to make them encodable to NSData?

Methods I use for encoding/decoding:

```
-(NSString *)stringFromDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict{
    NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:data];
    [archiver encodeObject:dict forKey:@"dictKey"];
    [archiver finishEncoding];

    return [Base64 encode:data];
}

-(NSDictionary *)dictionaryFromString:(NSString *)string{
    NSData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithData:[Base64 decode:string]];
    NSKeyedUnarchiver *unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:data];
    NSDictionary *myDictionary = [unarchiver decodeObjectForKey:@"dictKey"];
    [unarchiver finishDecoding];
    return myDictionary;

}
```

Error I get:

```
-[UITouchesEvent encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Please let me know if I'm missing any important info regarding debugging. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to have `UITouch` or `UITouchesEvent` adapt the [UICoding](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol. This means it must support these methods:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder;
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder;
```

I haven't tried this myself, but it should work if you do this in a class category. The difficulty will be to find out what you need to encode so it can be decoded again into a correct instance, if that's what you need.

Comment: Thanks, but as I said, I already have UITouch encoding working. I'm trying to figure out how to do this with UITouchesEvent.

Comment: My bad, then of course you'll have to do that for the `UITouchesEvent` class. But I don't think this will be easy.